# In C++, is a constructor with only default arguments a default constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-constructor, default-arguments

In the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int x=0);
};
```

Does the constructor count as a default constructor?

Comment: The default constructor is automatically generated by the compiler when you don't define one.  So I'd say no, it's not because you've defined it

Comment: @peacemaker actually, a default constructor is a constructor with no arguments

Comment: @peacemaker: You're confusing default as in "provided by default" with default as in "called by default".  The standard uses the term to refer to the latter.

Comment: @peacemaker: And "automatically generated" is formally called "implicitly declared" or "implicitly defined", depending on context. So you're actually referring to "implicitly declared constructors".

Comment: Thanks for the terminology updates guys!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++98 §12.1/5 *(emphasis mine)*:

> A default constructor for a class X is **a constructor of X that can be called without an argument.** If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a default constructor is implicitly declared.

So yes, it does count as a default constructor.  [See also](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.4).

Comment: I thought I read that somewhere once. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @panickal Might be worth noting the example is also a conversion constructor and still carries with it implicit conversions.

Comment: C++11 changes the second sentence slightly: _If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted._